# How to find tty from which a particular cmd "scp" is executed

Tags: process, forensics

How can I find out who executed a particular command and which terminal was used to run it?

---

*Original*:

How can I know particular cmd is executed by whom and to know about my terminal

Comment: Can you rephrase this question so it's a little clearer?

Comment: Do you mean, "what ps command should I use to determine who's using scp?" That would be ps -ef | grep scp

Comment: possible duplicate of [monitoring activity on my computer.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4275/monitoring-activity-on-my-computer)

Answer (score 7):

To see what commands are being executed you use "ps -ef".  This will tell you what **everyone** is doing though which is usually too much information.

To narrow it down to find out who is running a particular command you might add a "grep" filter like so:

`ps -ef | grep scp`

This will return all scp commands but it might also return the grep command looking for scp and any other commands with the letters scp embedded in them since grep is just matching the string.  So you may need to get clever with the expression given to grep (a lot of times you just need to quote it and add a space:

`ps -ef | grep "scp "`

or even better leverage regular expressions and:

`ps -ef | grep "[s]cp "`

If you know the user and just want to know what they are running then "ps -fu" is your friend.  For instance

`ps -fu tom`

Which can, of course, be combined with grep to get tom's scp processes:

`ps -fu tom | grep "[s]cp "`

Column 6 is the tty.

Comment: +1 for the 'grep "[s]cp"' trick - it's what I use in a script I call 'procname'.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tty` to find out the file name of the terminal connected to standard input.

For the latter part of your question, `sudo` or `su` and then `grep -c 'command' /home/username/.bash_history`.